# CKEdtior allow <html>, <head>, <body> without using fullPage: true

Tags: configuration, tags, ckeditor

CKEdtior strips `<html>, <head> and <body>` with the default configuration setting `fullPage = false`. This is most noticable when you paste HTML into the 'source' view, then turn the source view off and on again.

However, if you make `fullPage = true` then the editor automatically adds these tags to each textarea.

How can I edit the config so that these tags are allowed (not stripped out), but not added to each editor by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible (without hacking). If you want to be able to use these tags, then the full page mode must be true. The reason is that CKEditor places the content that you load into it in a `<body>` element (or different element depending on the editor type).

The hack that came to my mind is using [source protection](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-protectedSource) to find content before `<body>` and after it and secure it. See a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hkx8g8b8/1/

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    protectedSource: [
        /^[\s\S]*<body>\s*/i,
        /\s*<\/body>[\s\S]*$/i
   ]
} );
```

If you want to allow using some attributes in `<body>` tag you need to extend this regexp of course.